# Is there any Dot Net service to count the words in a Xliff file?

Tags: c#, .net, translation, translate, language-translation

I have a xliff file as following:

```
<xliff version="2.0" srcLang="en" trgLang="de" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0">   <file id="9_583">
    <unit id="9_583" name="Alloy Track" type="EPiServer:Content">
      <segment id="PageName">
        <source>Alloy Track</source>
        <target>Alloy Track</target>
      </segment>
      <segment id="UniqueSellingPoints">
        <source>
          Shared timeline
          Project emails
          To-do lists
          Workflows
          Status reports
        </source>
      </segment>
    </unit>   </file> </xliff>
```

Question: Is there any Dot Net service (C#) to count the word in the xliff file?

Comment: Words would be in the <source> element? You can use Linq to XML to extract the content of that tag and do the calculation. Check also https://github.com/fmuecke/XliffParser, it might help

Comment: Hi Rui Jarimba, thank for your answer. I just need a word count service to count the words in the file. I do not calculate manually.

Comment: It appears to be a dialect of XML. "Words" doesn't really have an immediately obvious *meaning* when you're talking about XML. So we're asking *you*, for example, what count you'd expect to get back for this example you've shown us, and some *explanation* of what's included and what isn't.

Comment: do you need to count all words including tags(e.g. <source>) or just the words between the tags?

Answer (score 1):

As someone from localization industry — word-counting is

- commonly performed by the *[CAT tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation)* during the *Analysis*

  CAT tools are usually using proprietary algorithms (no *de-facto* standard was ever established), most of them trying to produce results similar to the MS Word;
- done on *Source* and *Target* content separately;
- *natural language* dependent (there are languages not using spaces as word separators).

While it would help to know what are you trying to achieve by counting the words, generally, you can manipulate the XLIFF2 documents using the open-source [XLIFF OM](https://github.com/Microsoft/XLIFF2-Object-Model/tree/master/Xliff.OM) to access the *Source* or *Target* content and then get the approximate word count using known word boundaries as specified by [UNICODE Standard Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries).

**In theory, the [gmx-v](https://github.com/a-h/gmx-v), an implementation of the [LISA GMX/V standard](https://www.gala-global.org/gmx-v-10), could do this for you, but I haven't tested it, so I cannot guarantee sanity of its results and its ability to process XLIFF2 documents.**

---

Anyway, I would suggest using an XLIFF2 capable CAT tool with an API to automate the analysis, if the results are to be used for anything else than set the baseline expectations. This way you can make use of additional features they offer ([TM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory)/[MT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_translation) leverage, [fuzzy matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_matching_(computer-assisted_translation)), repetitions).

---

For instance, [Okapi Framework](http://okapiframework.org/) > Rainbow > [Pipeline](http://okapiframework.org/javadoc/index.html) > [Word Count Step](http://okapiframework.org/wiki/index.php?title=Word_Count_Step), could be also a solution, though it does not meet the .NET requirement.

---

If you are the creator of the sample XLIFF2 document in the question, I could provide some feedback re the structure and the metadata to improve the interoperability.